# How to use map container?

Tags: c++

I'm not very experienced with maps and was hoping someone could give me some pointers and examples on how to use them. The goal for this map is to keep track of how many customers a waiter serves in a restaurant. Once the restaurant closes, I would then list each waiter and the number of people served. This is the map as it appears in the h file.

```
std::map<std::string,int> servers;
```

The waiters can be represented as "waiterName". What would an example of adding on customers served to a waiter look like? And how would I list the waiters and customers served?

```
cout << waiterName << " served " << (customers served by this waiter) << endl;
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you are unsure about how to use a particular standard library class then look at http://en.cppreference.com.  If you look at [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), check out the `operator[]` or `std::map:at` sections. They contain examples.

Comment: There must be hundreds of tutorials on using `std::map` out there in google land. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=C%2B%2B+map+tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::pair<std::string, int> const &s)
{
    os << s.first << " served " << s.second;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> servers;
    servers["foo"]++;
    servers["foo"]++;
    servers["foo"]++;
    servers["foo"]++;
    servers["bar"]++;
    servers["bar"]++;

    for (auto s : servers)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(auto const &waiterStat: servers) std::cout << waiterStat.first << " served " << waiterStat.second << " customers.\n";
```

You can use `operator[]` to access a particular key's value, `find()` to search for an entry, insertion, iteration and others represent map as a collection of key-value pairs.